# Trying to make a recursive crawl spider with python. SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, syntax-error, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl more then one page in scrappy, my function indeed returns the first start url, but I can't manage to make work the rules for the spider.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem



class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/"]



    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*?s=.*',), restrict_xpaths('a[@class="button next"]',)), callback='parse', follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]'):
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            yield item`
```

I get this error

> SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

UPDATE:

Thanks to the answer below. There is no syntax error, but my crawler just stays in the same page and doesn't crawl.

Updated code

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['.*?s=.*'], restrict_xpaths=('a[@class="button next"]')), 
        callback='parse', follow=True, ),
)


    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]'):
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: Should it be `restrict_xpaths=('a[@class="button next"]',))`? Looks like maybe you forgot the `=`.

Comment: yeah i checked and it fixed the syntax error, but still isnt crawling other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so i found whats the problem i was using the method parse:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]'):
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

after reading this i found out my problem.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider

CrawlSpider uses parse as a method, so i had to rename my function to this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]'):
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to this (Python 3)

```
>>> print("hello")
hello
>>> print("hello", end=",,")
hello,,
>>> print(end=",,", "hello")
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

The line:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*?s=.*',), restrict_xpaths('a[@class="button next"]',)), callback='parse', follow=True),)
```

must be called as:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths('a[@class="button next"]'),allow=('.*?s=.*',)), callback='parse', follow=True),)
```

Comment: it gives me this output NameError: name 'restrict_xpaths' is not defined

Comment: @2one2 This answer may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394432/scrapy-restrict-xpath-syntax-error

Comment: well with this i have no syntax error, but my code isnt scraping other pages, just the start url

Comment: @2one2 Try thinking about it, if you can't get it to work then ask another question.